# Set Filters in Google Sheet using a value

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've a Google Sheet that has 20 columns, one of the columns is "Status". I would like to set Filters to the sheet to filter OUT (exclude) all rows that have Status = 'Completed'. How can I do it? Thanks in advance for your help.

Here's the code I have so far...

```
function filterSheet() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var aSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Target Sheet');
  var lastRow = aSheet.getLastRow();
  var lastColumn = aSheet.getLastColumn();
  var sheetId = aSheet.getSheetId();

  var filterSettings = {
    "range": {
      "sheetId": sheetId,
      "startRowIndex": 0,
      "endRowIndex": lastRow,
      "startColumnIndex": 0,
      "endColumnIndex": lastColumn

      //how do I include condition here to filter out rows where columnIndex 2 (column C) = 'Completed'?

    }
  };

  var requests = [{
    "setBasicFilter": {
      "filter": filterSettings
    }
  }];
  Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate({'requests': requests}, ssId);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```js
function filterSheet() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var aSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Target Sheet');
  var lastRow = aSheet.getLastRow();
  var lastColumn = aSheet.getLastColumn();
  var sheetId = aSheet.getSheetId();

  var filterSettings = {
    "range": {
      "sheetId": sheetId,
      "startRowIndex": 0,
      "endRowIndex": lastRow,
      "startColumnIndex": 0,
      "endColumnIndex": lastColumn    
    }
  };

  filterSettings.criteria[columnIndex] = {
    "hiddenValues": ["Completed"]
  };

  var requests = [{
    "setBasicFilter": {
      "filter": filterSettings
    }
  }];
  Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate({'requests': requests}, ssId);
}
```

More info on FilterCriteria: https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/FilterCriteria

Comment: Thanks for your response. Being a newbie to scripts, how do I modify the existing string of hidden values to include "Canceled" status? I tried using "hiddenValues": ["Completed", "Canceled"] but that doesn't seem to work.