# Google Script Filter Range for one value

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I would like to filter a google sheet range for rows that only contain a particular value of "Bob" in Column 1. My code so far lets me filter **out** the rows that have Bob in Col 1. I need to opposite, I want to return the rows that only have "Bob" in col 1. So where the filterSettings is not the hiddenValues or something like
"filterSettings['criteria'][columnIndex] **== !**{'hiddenValues': [filterCriteria]"

My query is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49134212/set-filters-in-google-sheet-using-a-value), but I don't want to exlude the row with the filter criteria, I want these to be the only remaining rows.

Code.gs

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var filterCriteria = 'Bob';


    var filterSettings = {};

    filterSettings.range = {
        sheetId: ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1').getSheetId()
                            };

    filterSettings.criteria = {};
        var columnIndex = 0;
    filterSettings['criteria'][columnIndex] = {
        'hiddenValues': [filterCriteria]
                                               };

    var request = {
      setBasicFilter: {
      filter: filterSettings
                      }
                  };
    Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate({'requests': [request]}, ss.getId());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your sample case, you want to exclude the values except for "Bob". If my understanding is correct, how about this modification?

#### Modification points :

- Use `type` to `filterCriteria`.

  - `type` is `TEXT_CONTAINS`. And the value is "Bob".
  - By this, only values including "Bob" are left.

#### Modified script :

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

var filterCriteria = {"type":"TEXT_CONTAINS","values":[{"userEnteredValue":"Bob"}]}; // Modified

var filterSettings = {};
filterSettings.range = {sheetId: ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1').getSheetId()};
filterSettings.criteria = {};
var columnIndex = 0;

filterSettings['criteria'][columnIndex] = {'condition': filterCriteria}; // Modified

var request = {setBasicFilter: {filter: filterSettings}};
Logger.log(JSON.stringify({'requests': [request]}))
Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate({'requests': [request]}, ss.getId());
```

#### Note :

- This modified script supposes that you can use Sheets API.

#### References :

- [SetBasicFilterRequest](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#setbasicfilterrequest)
- [ConditionType](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets#conditiontype)

If I misunderstand your question, please tell me. I would like to modify it.

Comment: @Derek Morgan I'm glad your issue was solved. Thank you, too.

Comment: Hello Tanaike!
I was reading this response but this is very new to me (the way to solve this problem and this kind of code).
Question: How do I use the data I get from this script? How do I copy it to another sheet?
I could insert this in my script but I don't know how to access the result. Is this Javascript?
Thanks

Comment: @Luis Alberto Delgado de la Flo Thank you for your comment. I would like to support you. But unfortunately, I cannot understand about your situation. In order to understand about it, can you post it as new question by including the detail information? By this, it will help users including me think of the issue and solution. If you can cooperate to resolve your issue, I'm glad.

Comment: @Tanaike Thanks for your response. I was just doing some research about this and I found out this is 'metadata' and is a whole new world for me. I'm reading some blogs about it and see it's useful to create some CRUD kind operations on my sheets. I'll keep reading and come with a question if any :)