# Error "Expected OAuth 2 access token" on container-bound script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I want to filter a google sheet for one value only, as in [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50975624/google-script-filter-range-for-one-value).

I have activated sheets-api and looked through documentation, how to add oauth2 verification. Concluded, that it should happen automatically, since the script is container-bound.

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName('Aufgaben')); // change active sheet

var filterCriteria = {"type":"TEXT_CONTAINS","values":[{"userEnteredValue": "0001" }]}; // set filter

var filterSettings = {};
filterSettings.range = {sheetId: ss.getSheetByName('Aufgaben').getSheetId(), startRowIndex: 1};
filterSettings.criteria = {};
var columnIndex = 4;

filterSettings['criteria'][columnIndex] = {'condition': filterCriteria}; // Modified

var request = {setBasicFilter: {filter: filterSettings}};
Browser.msgBox(JSON.stringify({'requests': [request]})); //only works, when this line is added!
Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate({'requests': [request]}, ss.getId()); `
```

The code works, but ONLY if I add `Browser.msgBox`one line above `Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate()`. Otherwise I get this error: *Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.
    at onEdit(test:127)*

Since I've already spent hours trying to solve this. 
Thank you.

Comment: I cannot understand about `The code works, but ONLY if I add Browser.msgBoxone line above Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate()`. When the script is run by script editor, it works. But if it's run by the simple trigger and custom function, such error occurs. Custom function cannot use `Browser.msgBox`. So if you run it with the simple trigger, how about modifying to the installable trigger? [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) At that time, please modify the function name in order to prevent the double running. If I misunderstood your situation, I apologize.

Comment: My code is triggered by `onEdit()`. I inserted `Browser.msgBox...`as a simple way to check the parameters and all of a sudden, the code did't produce the error, that was chance. I just don't understand, how this could prevent the error? If I comment out or delete `Browser.msgBox...`I get the oauth-error.
Even works with `Browser.msgBox('hello')`. Very strange.

Comment: You need "installable" edit trigger instead of a simple one.

Comment: Thank you for replying. At first, I have to apologize for my poor English skill. When your script is used, [TheMaster`s comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57344419/error-expected-oauth-2-access-token-on-container-bound-script?noredirect=1#comment101185094_57344419) will resolve your issue.

Comment: @Tanaike I appreciate your help. I don't know why, but with sheets-api I did not get it to work. But [ADW 's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57345370/11874332) worked for me – Google Apps Script Spreadsheet Service instead.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps the

> // set filter

is causing problems?

This worked for me without oauth2 verification:

```
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName('Aufgaben')); // change active sheet

  var filterCriteria = {"type":"TEXT_CONTAINS","values":[{"userEnteredValue": "4210"}]}; // Modified

  var filterSettings = {};
  filterSettings.range = {sheetId: ss.getSheetByName('Aufgaben').getSheetId(), startRowIndex: 1};
  filterSettings.criteria = {};
  var columnIndex = 4;

  filterSettings['criteria'][columnIndex] = {'condition': filterCriteria}; // Modified

  var request = {setBasicFilter: {filter: filterSettings}};
  Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate({'requests': [request]}, ss.getId());
```

---

**Edit**

I'm was not able to replicate the issue with the code you provided. Even with the message box, I got an error.

If you are triggering the filtering function when the sheet is edited, you may want to try a version of the Google Apps Script Spreadsheet Service:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var criteria = SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria().whenTextContains("0001").build();
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var lastCol = sheet.getLastColumn();
  var range = sheet.getRange(2, 1, lastRow - 1, lastCol);
  range.createFilter().setColumnFilterCriteria(4, criteria);
}
```

**Refs**

[newFilterCriteria()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#newFilterCriteria())

[whenTextContains(text)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/filter-criteria-builder#whenTextContains(String))

[createFilter()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#createFilter())

[setColumnFilterCriteria(columnPosition, filterCriteria)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/filter#setColumnFilterCriteria(Integer,FilterCriteria))

Comment: Thanks for your reply, @ADW. That was my mistake, intered `// set filter` in the middle of the line instead of replacing `// Modified`.

Comment: That worked! I wasn't able to find the functions you provided for using Google Apps Script Spreadsheet Service, neither here nor on google. Thank you.